# How to register spring boot admin client to spring boot admin client through eureka?

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I already started a stand alone eureka service and a `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotated spring boot admin server. And the admin server was already registered in the eureka successfully. Now question is how to register a spring boot application to the admin server through eureka? 
PS: without eureka, we need to add config: `spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8080` in the admin client to register the client to the admin server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client apps are regular eureka apps they should show up in the admin server. 
There is also a short section on this in the docs: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#discover-clients-via-spring-cloud-discovery